# How to capitalize all Rails Activerecord form validation messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, yaml

I am trying to perform a simple customization on all of the validation error messages on a form in my rails app. Simply, I want to go from: `can't be blank` and `is invalid` to `Can't be blank`, `Is invalid`, etc. Is there a way to do this in my translations that won't require customizing every single individual error message?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a class or some way of creating a css selector you can use:

```
.error-msg:first-letter{
  text-transform: capitalize
}
```

Another option is you could change your `config/locales/en.yml` file like so:

```
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      blank: "Can't be blank"
      invalid: "Is invalid"
      ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing it in your view using the [capitalize](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize) method.

In your view:

```
<% m.errors.each do |attr, msg|  %>
  <%= msg.capitalize %>
<% end %>
```